# How to separate this to 2 different loop

Tags: python

I'm new to python and I want to make a program that validate user input for name and age. If name contains numbers it will print name can't be numbers and if age contains characters it will print age can't be characters. So I have the program that works but I want to make it ask for thing 1 by 1 until conditions are met then move on to the next.

```
name = None
age = None

while True:
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    age = input("Whats your age?: ")
    try:
        val = int(age)
        char = str(name)
        print("Hello %s" % str.capitalize(char))
        print("You will turn 100 in %d" % (100-val))
        break
    except ValueError:
         print("Your name can't contain numbers.")
         print("Your age can't contain characters")
```

This will ask for both name and age first then validate.
I tried to separate it to 2 while loops but then it feeds me back error.
Please help.

Comment: Put the `age` input and validation in one loop, and the `name` input and validation in a second loop.  What is the difficulty?

Comment: Casting name to `str` does not fail if there are numbers in it, btw

Comment: Right.  Since `name` is already a string, `str(name)` is utterly pointless.

Answer (score 1):

This does what you're trying to do.  It's just a matter of two `while` loops.

```
name = None
while True:
    name = input("What's your name?: ")
    if any(c.isdigit() for c in name):
        print("Your name can't contain numbers.")
    else:
        break

age = None
while True:
    age = input("Whats your age?: ")
    try:
        val = int(age)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("Your age can't contain characters")

print("Hello %s" % name.capitalize())
print("You will turn 100 in %d years" % (100-val))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use "Try except" for checking the age, but not for checking the name in the way that you are doing it. For checking if the name contains a digit, you could use the ".isdigit()" function and check every character in the name string. I have tried to make a little example underneath, however I haven't tested the code, but I'm pretty sure it works.

```
def contains_number(string):
for char in string:
    if char.isdigit():
        return True

name = input("Enter your name: ")

if contains_number(name):
    print("Your name contains a number!")
```

Comment: Surely better is `return any(c.isdigit() for c in string)`.

Comment: @TimRoberts You are probably right, but I was trying to give some information that might be more intuitive to a beginner, than just using the any-function.